# TITAN : Cassandrathrift vs Astyanax performance

Tags: cassandra, thrift, titan, astyanax, rexster

I am using a TITAN-0.4.3, REXSTER 2.4 over Cassandra(6 node cluster) & Elasticsearch. My use case requires to bulk upload vertices and edges into the graph at a time. Presently the rate at which adding new vertex+edge is very slow ( ~45 / sec ), and the targeted is ~1000 vertices / sec. Presently I am using Astyanax connecter to cassandra ( which has load balancing and failover detection capabilities). Is there any other advantages or dis-advantages for Astyanax over Thrift (Cassandrathrift) connecter or vice-versa?

Please advise!

### Astyanax

```
    <graph>
        ...
        <properties>
            <storage.backend>cassandra</storage.backend>
            ...
```

### Cassandrathrift

```
    <graph>
        ...
        <properties>
            <storage.backend>cassandrathrift</storage.backend>
            ...
```

Answer (score 2):

There are some important differences between these two settings.  You touched on the first set of differences by mentioning "load balancing and failover detection" when using `cassandra`.  The other set of differences relate to how each keeps data in memory and how it is sent over the wire.  For bulk loading scenarios, I think that you will find a generally better experience with `cassandra` as your setting, as bulk-loading under `cassandrathrift` might hit GC issues depending on your loading strategy.  Of course, this is just a generality and somewhat dependent on your loading strategy.  I'd suggest that you simply try both settings given your load and see what works best.